# How to add ABS strftime in SQLite IOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm working on some DB task where I need to fetch records according to closest date from today. Like the below screenshot.

[image: Record date in DB]

Now what I want is that today is 2017-05-18, so I should get the record with on_date 2017-09-22, and when the on_date crosses/will cross 2017-09-22 then I get a record with on_date 2017-10-04 and so on.

I tried using ORDER BY ABS( strftime( "%s", on_date ) - strftime( "%s", '2017-05-18' ) ) ASC with my query and it show me the record for date 2017-09-22.

But if I change ORDER BY ABS( strftime( "%s", on_date ) - strftime( "%s", '2017-09-23' ) ) ASC then I don't get the record for date 2017-10-04 but get record for date 2017-09-22

Comment: Please provide a `.dump`of a suitable toy database from sqlite commandline too, as part of the [mcve].

Comment: Your sample input does not have a record for 2017-10-04. Is that a mistake in your sample input? If there is no such record in your databasse either, then why do you expect it to be listed for your query?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the ordering of the date records is the unwanted behaviour you describe (it is not entirely clear), especially the position of 2017-10-04 between the other results.

I think you have not noticed three little but important facts:

- 201**7**-10-04 record **is not** in your sample input
- 201**6**-10-04 record **is** in your sample input,
  but it has a much higher distance to the reference dates you tried
- 2017-09-23 is closer to 2017-09-22 than to 2017-10-04

Keeping these in mind, your query seems to me to be working just fine.
Forgive me for believing that you mixed up 2016 and 2017 when checking the results, because you were concentrating on months and days.

To demonstrate, I made this mcve (on SQLite 3.18.0 2017-03-28):

```
CREATE TABLE toy (on_date date);
INSERT INTO toy VALUES('2017-09-22T00:00:00.000Z');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES('2017-04-11T00:00:00.000Z');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES('2016-10-20T00:00:00.000Z');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES('2016-10-04T00:00:00.000Z');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES('2017-10-04T00:00:00.000Z'); -- intentionally added
COMMIT;
```

Then tried exactly the queries you describe:

1):

```
select on_date from toy 
ORDER BY ABS( strftime( "%s", on_date ) - strftime( "%s", '2017-05-18' ) ) ASC;
```

Output(10-04 in line 3):

```
2017-04-11T00:00:00.000Z
2017-09-22T00:00:00.000Z
2017-10-04T00:00:00.000Z
2016-10-20T00:00:00.000Z
2016-10-04T00:00:00.000Z
```

2):

```
select on_date from toy
ORDER BY ABS( strftime( "%s", on_date ) - strftime( "%s", '2017-09-23' ) ) ASC;
```

Output (10-04 in line 2):

```
2017-09-22T00:00:00.000Z
2017-10-04T00:00:00.000Z
2017-04-11T00:00:00.000Z
2016-10-20T00:00:00.000Z
2016-10-04T00:00:00.000Z
```

Then I tried additionally with 2017-09-30, which is closer to 10-04 than to 9-22).

3)

```
select on_date from toy
ORDER BY ABS( strftime( "%s", on_date ) - strftime( "%s", '2017-09-30' ) ) ASC;
```

Output(10-04 in line 1):

```
2017-10-04T00:00:00.000Z
2017-09-22T00:00:00.000Z
2017-04-11T00:00:00.000Z
2016-10-20T00:00:00.000Z
2016-10-04T00:00:00.000Z
```

Explanation:

Please note, I added the record with 2017-10-04 to the database, because you seem to assume it is present.
But your sample input does not contain it.
I think that part of what you describe as the unwanted behaviour is caused by that missing record.

On top of that, your experimental date 2017-09-23 is still much closer to 2017-09-22 than it is to 2017-10-04. That is why I added the query with 2017-09-30.
That one gives 2017-10-04 as first result.

If I am right with my assumptions (ignore the rest if I am wrong), then I believe you might have spotted your mistake while making a mcve, instead of only making a screenshot.
Allow me to recommend spending the effort on making a real, textual mcve in the future.
Check the term "rubber ducking", it is very useful and making a really good mcve is practically the same, just with a rubber duck that actually understands at least the syntax of what you are talking about.
To get the best benefit of rubber mcve ducking, create a toy database in which you see the same problem, then do a `.dump` from SQLite commandline tool.
Just by that, you have 90% of a really good mcve.